# How can i create a proper setup for shooting bedding if my studio is too small?

Tags: studio-setup, backdrops

How can i create a proper setup for shooting bedding if my studio is too small & so is my bedroom?
Need some innovative ideas where i can shoot some blankets, pillows, linen etc on a bed and how we can make the room/ bed look different so that the photos don't all look the same

Comment: If it is too small, it is too small.  What specific kinds of problems are you trying to overcome?

Comment: @AJHenderson We had an idea of shooting in a hotel but dont know if it would be allowed & if it is how can i give one room different looks

Comment: If the curtains in the frame, it can be replaced relatively cheaply and easily

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are selling very expensive luxury beddings, do not worry about being particularly creative about the surroundings. Dress up your bed, and shoot the same setup. E.g. see how [IKEA](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/catalog/categories/departments/bedroom/10680/?sorting=newest&cid=gb%3Eps%3E%3EBedroom+Generic+-+Bedding+-+Exact%3Ego%3Ebedding%3Emckv%3Es4wy5B7BE_dc%3Epcrid%3E35520762582) solves this very nicely. You do not need to make a picture of the whole bed, just a part of the bed is sufficient (and actually highly recommended). Just make sure all distinctive details are on the photo.

Now, if you really want to have different rooms, you can ask a hotel owner whether he allows this. Probably a nuisance for him, and you will have to compensate him for that.

The most expensive is to rent a studio and create different interieurs. A bit cheaper if you reuse the same bed and just change the backdrop.

But again, this is a very serious overkill I guess. Your customers mostly want to have as much detail on the product as they can get, and will not really care about the surrounding. If you shoot the very same setup, you actually create a rhythmic pattern, which is not particularly unpleasant.